# 'System.LimitException: Maximum stack depth reached: 1001' Error message

Tags: apex, controller, describesobject

What is the meaning of the error message:

> System.LimitException: Maximum stack depth reached: 1001

I am trying below code, and on previewing the page from 'Developer Console', this error appears.

VF Page:

```
<apex:page controller="ObjectDetails">
    <apex:pageBlock title="Object Details in this environment" id="oD_list">
        <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!objectdetail}" var="o">
            <apex:column value="{!o.objectname}"/apex:column>
            <apex:column value="{!o.apiname}/apex:column>
        <apex:pageBlockTable>
    <apex:pageBlock>
<apex:page>
```

Apex Class:

```
public class ObjectDetails {

    String objectName, apiName;
    List<ObjectDetails> ODList=new List<ObjectDetails>();
    ObjectDetails odObl=new ObjectDetails();
    public List<ObjectDetails> getObjectDetail(){
         for(Schema.SObjectType sO: Schema.getGlobalDescribe().values()){
            Schema.DescribeSObjectResult oRE = sO.getDescribe();
            odObl.objectName=oRE.getLabel();
            odObl.apiName=oRE.getName();
            ODList.add(odObl);
        }
        return ODList;
    }
    public String getobjectName(){
        return objectName;
    }
    public String getapiName(){
        return objectName;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code would be a lot easier to read if you spent just a few more characters on informative variable names. Out of context, would you have any idea what `odObl` is supposed to mean? It't not very clear to me even seeing your entire code snippet. Omit abbreviations wherever possible and just type the dang thing out.

Answer (score 4):

When method is called space is reserved on the [stack](https://www.cs.umd.edu/class/sum2003/cmsc311/Notes/Mips/stack.html) for the arguments to the method and the local variables inside the method so part of a block of memory (of limited size) is used. And methods can call other methods.

When that chain of method calls gets very long, it is most often because of a programming error where a method (or chain of methods) calls itself resulting in a never-ending cycle that will never return a result. Salesforce detects and throws the error you see to alert you of that situation.

Right now I can't see the cause of such a never-ending cycle in the code you have posted.

One mistake I do see is that you are adding the same instance of `odObl` many times to the list. Also the `ODList` is best moved so:

```
public class ObjectDetails {

    String objectName, apiName;

    public List<ObjectDetails> getObjectDetail() {

        // Better to not have this in every instance of ObjectDetails
        List<ObjectDetails> ODList=new List<ObjectDetails>();

        for(Schema.SObjectType sO: Schema.getGlobalDescribe().values()){
            Schema.DescribeSObjectResult oRE = sO.getDescribe();

            // Moved this to inside the loop
            ObjectDetails odObl=new ObjectDetails();

            odObl.objectName=oRE.getLabel();
            odObl.apiName=oRE.getName();
            ODList.add(odObl);
        }

        return ODList;
    }

    public String getobjectName() {
        return objectName;
    }

    public String getapiName() {
        // Changed this too
        return apiName;
    }
}
```

Comment: I added an answer of my own that explains what happened. Since you stated that you weren't sure what happened, I felt it would probably be useful to know.

Comment: @sfdcfox Thanks, yes that didn't occur to me but makes sense. +1 for your answer.

Answer (score 4):

The problem with your code is that when a VF page is constructed, all of the variables are initialized. As a part of that initialization, the members are also initialized. Since you've defined an initialization that is recursive, you end up with the stack being exhausted. Here's a trivial example that shows your problem:

```
public class StackOverflow {
  StackOverflow member = new StackOverflow();
}
```

Here, when you create a new StackOverflow, it contains one element, `member`, that must be initialized, so a new instance is created. This new instance (we're now at 2), has one element, `member`, that must be initialized, so a new instance is created (we're now at 3)... This would happen *ad infinitum*, but the system has a safety in place that detects this type of infinite recursion.

The relevant parts of your code are:

```
public class ObjectDetails {
  // ... //
  ObjectDetails odObl=new ObjectDetails();
  // ... //
}
```

Which should look familiar to the first code example.

This is a pretty hard problem to spot if you don't know what you're looking for, but once you've seen it and understand its cause, you should be able to avoid it in the future.

The system allows recursion because it is useful in limited cases, such as calculating factorials:

```
public Decimal factorial(Decimal value) {
  return value == 1? 1: value * factorial(value - 1);
}
```

Whenever you need to perform a repeated, nested method, you may want to use recursion. However, because of the limits of the stack, be aware that the following code would result in an error:

```
Decimal result = factorial(1001);
```

When you run in to situations where the recursion depth is unknown, and potentially much larger than 1,000 (but not infinite), then you have to write your own stack-management techniques. I doubt you'll ever find a need for this, but you should be aware that it is possible to do so using an "infinite" while loop.

For example, for factorial, above, you could write it like this:

```
Decimal factorial(Decimal value) {
  Decimal result = value;
  while(value > 1) {
    result *= --value;
  }
  return result;
}
```

This example also demonstrates why we write recursive methods. They are often shorter than writing a non-recursive alternative. You should prefer recursion when it makes sense, which is usually the case in common algorithms.

As KeithC said, you need to move the ObjectDetails to be local to the method. This is generally a best practice. Each variable's *scope* should be as small as possible. If a variable is only used in one method, it should generally be defined in that method.

As a side note, keep in mind that the variable has to be initialized *inside* the loop. If you do it outside the loop, you end up with only one "element", repeated over and over, with the contents of each element being overwritten by the latest value.

You can see the problem here:

```
public class Demo {
  public Integer value;
}
public Demo[] makeListIncorrectly(Integer size) {
  Demo[] results = new Demo[0];
  Demo item = new Demo();
  while(size-- > 0) {
    item.value = size;
    results.add(item);
  }
  return results;
}
```

This would return erroneous output like this:

```
Demo[4] results = [0: Demo(value=0), 1: Demo(value=0), 2: Demo(value=0), 3: Demo(value=0)];
```

Instead of the expected results:

```
Demo[4] results = [0: Demo(value=3), 1: Demo(value=2), 2: Demo(value=1), 3: Demo(value=0)];
```

This is because each element in the list would contain the same "reference." Instead, you need to create new instances, which would each have their own "reference":

```
public class Demo {
  public Integer value;
}
public Demo[] makeListCorrectly(Integer size) {
  Demo[] results = new Demo[0];
  while(size-- > 0) {
    Demo item = new Demo();
    item.value = size;
    results.add(item);
  }
  return results;
}
```

I've also written other answers about how memory references work, which you may want to read up on. Generally speaking, though, each time you use "new", you get a single piece of memory to work with. If you want a bunch of different memory places to work with, you need to use a "new" for each one.

I would recommend reading more about [Variables](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_variables.htm) in the documentation.